# How to do a Django/Javascript combination; specifically - window.location

Tags: javascript, python, django, phaser-framework

I have a Django/Phaser/Javascript set up like this:
Project ----> Djangotemplates---------> Djangotemplates + example + static

In the example folder is:

example ----->  templates -------> about.html + constr.html + game.html + index.html

These are all django static files, no base.html, nothing really complicated except I have one problem.

That is the main.js file in the js folder in the static folder.

A link in the index.html file takes you to the game.html file which is basically the one single Phaser file that opens up the main.js file (that runs the game).  Everything works so far, including the game itself.  So...  Index.html goes to game.html to main.js

Now I have a method to get back to the main index.html file (from the game) - but THAT doesn't work.

Like this:

```
else{
if(flagGameover){
console.log("GOTO GAMEOVER");
window.location = 'index.html';
```

Now I've tried all sorts of things to make that last line work, but ?!!%*^?!##???
It seems if I put any Django code in the main.js file, such as:

window.location = "{% url 'index' %}";
window.location = {% static '/example/templates/index.html' %}";  (and many more things taken off the Net, like script tags )

Putting in any Django code in the main.js seems to result in white screens or Not Found.

Yet I can have the main.js access the images in an access folder with no problem;
for example:

```
game.load.spritesheet('fw', '/static/assets/fw(180x244).png', 186, 244, 5);  Works!
```

No problem, - also no Django being used in that file (main.js), just paths.
I have my urls.py and views.py correctly configured for the 4 html files in the templates folder - they all work; it's just the last line,  window.location.....

I don't know enough about the connection between Django and javascript to figure this out.
And I'd rather not have to rely on some other add-on program just for this, because I'm close to taking this out of development and into production.
Again, this is NOT a link or hover over; don't see how prerender, prefetch, etc. would work here.
Anyone have any suggestions how to fix the window.location problem?

Here is what it looks like when you run python manage.py runserver

Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/example/templates/index.html

Using the URLconf defined in djangotemplates.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
^admin/
^ ^$ [name='home']
^ ^about/$ [name='about']
^ ^constr/$ [name='constr']
^ ^game/$ [name='game']
```

The current path, example/templates/constr.html, didn't match any of these.

Note: home IS index.html

Comment: You can't put Django code in something that isn't a Django template. But ignoring the issue of JS altogether, what URL would you put into your browser to get that index template? That's exactly what you need to put into that location.

Comment: Looking at your code, I have three questions for you: 1) Have you loaded the static tag? 2). `{% static 'path_file_inside_the_static_folder' %}` **Keyword is static** folder.. 3). Have added the correct static url and root in the settings.py file?

Comment: It's a real conundrum; I set up an alternate project (without Django) - everything worked, including the window.location.  And at the same time, you're right - You can't put Django code in something that isn't a Django template, in this case a javascript/phaser page (main.js) in a js folder in the static folder.  Get nothing but either whitescreens or 404's Not Found. Deaspo - yes, I did all the standard Django steps, which is why, like I said - everything works EXCEPT the window.location

Comment: How about window.location.assign(), per [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)?

Comment: Hmmmm.... One of those might work, I'll fool around with it - since I also have to get to a Chinese and a Spanish page, might use more than one.  See if Django allows it.

Comment: @Mike OK, I'm using the 'assign' part of window.location
window.location.assign("http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
Now that works, takes the player back to the beginning.(reset)
But if I use it twice in the same main.js page, (Send the player to a different page) like this:
("GOTO GAMEOVER")      window.location.assign("http://127.0.0.1:8000/constr");   I get a 301 redirect that just keeps trying to connect but doesn't.  Halfway there, but....????  Possible to redirect the player to 2 different pages; reset and end of game???  Can use 2 DIFFERENT functions in the scripts?  NewDoc and NewDoc2??

Comment: I can only clutch at straws here. The `APPEND_SLASH` issue came to mind. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#append-slash) is the discussion in the docs.

Comment: OK, I figured it out.  If you want to send the player to 2 different pages in this Django/Phaser/Javascript combo, you can use (in the main.js file):

Comment: continuation: //resetGame(); window.location.assign("http://127.0.0.1:8000/");  AND console.log("GOTO GAMEOVER"); window.location.assign("http://127.0.0.1:8000/constr/");  In the game.html file you can have 2 scripts with the same name i.e. function newDoc() but different URL's, like example form the w3schools docs: function newDoc() {   window.location.assign method.
This method worked in Django.    #Have to closely watch your syntax too!